# What is the degree of a prime ideal?

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, ring-theory, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals

How is the degree of a prime ideal of an algebraic number field defined?

An algebraic number field is a finite extension of $\mathbb{Q}$, right?

A prime ideal is an ideal in a ring, i.e., a subgroup that defined a partition of the ring into residue classes, where its residue class ring is an integral domain, right?

But what is the degree of a prime ideal?

Comment: What do you mean with "degree"? I think you talk about the index of a prime ideal in the ring of integers of the number field.

Comment: See at http://www1.spms.ntu.edu.sg/~frederique/ANT10.pdf Definitions 3.3 and 3.4.

Comment: I found this term in a theorem... @ÁngelValencia

Comment: So, when we have that almost all prime ideals $\mathfrak{p}$ of an algebraic number field are of degree one, we mean that $\mathfrak{p} \mid p\mathcal{O}$ ? @Crostul

Comment: @MaryStar Yes, and that $[\mathcal{O}/ \mathfrak{p} : \mathbb{Z}/p \mathbb{Z}]=1$

Comment: What does $[\mathcal{O}/ \mathfrak{p} : \mathbb{Z}/p \mathbb{Z}]=1$ mean? @Crostul

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degree_of_a_field_extension

Comment: So does it mean that $\mathcal{O}/ \mathfrak{p} = \mathbb{Z}/p \mathbb{Z}$ ? @Crostul

Comment: Yes. That equality should be replaced with an isomorphism, but yes substantially this is the meaning.